# ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE exception from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, oracle12c, database-administration

I am trying to connect to Oracle from my c# code and retrieve some data from it.

Below is my sample code:

```
 DbCommon dbConn = CommonConfigMgr.GetConnFromPool(dbConnStr, dataSourceConfig.Schema);
        try
        {

            dbConn.Open();

            log.Debug("before constucting the oracle procedures... Line: 453");
            dbConn.CreateDbCommand("begin :username := eokutil.f_get_username_from_udcid(:udcid, :use_gobumap);end;", CommandType.Text);
            dbConn.AddCommandParameter(":username", username, ParameterDirection.Output);                
            dbConn.AddCommandParameter(":udcid", udcid, ParameterDirection.Input);
            dbConn.AddCommandParameter(":use_gobumap", 1, ParameterDirection.Input);
            log.Debug("after constructing the oracle procedures... Line: 458");


            dbConn.ExecuteNonQuery();


            Object returnValue = dbConn.GetCommandParameterValue(":username");

            if (returnValue == null || returnValue.ToString().Length == 0)
            {
                string message = String.Format("Unable to retrieve AX username for UDCID '{0}' from datasource '{1}'", udcid, dataSource);
                log.Error(message);
                throw new ApplicationException(message);
            }

            username = returnValue.ToString().ToUpper();
            log.InfoFormat("Record retrieved from eokutil.f_get_username_from_udcid: UDCID=>{0} USERNAME=>{1}", udcid, username);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            dbConn.RollbackTransaction();
            log.DebugFormat(e.Message);
            log.ErrorFormat("Fails to get AXC username from UDCID. {0}", e);
            throw e;
        }
```

But sometimes I am getting the following exception:

```
    Fails to get AXC username from UDCID. Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at XtenderSolutions.Administration.Database.DbCommonEx.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand cmd)
   at XtenderSolutions.UtilityLibrary.General.DbCommon.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at net.hedtech.bdm.sso.AxLoginHelper.GetAxUsernameFromUDCID(String dataSource, String udcid)
```

And for the rest of the calls I am getting something like this:

```
Fails to get AXC username from UDCID. Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException ORA-03135: connection lost contact
Process ID: 7009
Session ID: 799 Serial number: 33639    at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at XtenderSolutions.Administration.Database.DbCommonEx.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand cmd)
   at XtenderSolutions.UtilityLibrary.General.DbCommon.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at net.hedtech.bdm.sso.AxLoginHelper.GetAxUsernameFromUDCID(String dataSource, String udcid)
```

Any suggestion to overcome this?

> Same code is working fine for other clients. I am looking for something where oracle can make sure that it will will run each and every query after opening a connection

Clients are using :

> The DB version is Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release
>   12.1.0.2.0
>
> ODAC versions are 12.1.0.2.0.

Please help me with this.

Is there any way of reconnecting the connection and do the same step again?

Is it possible to do it from Oracle side?

As you can see we are using some 3rd party, and there connection pooling we are using. If it is a problem with connection pooling how to overcome that from our code?

Comment: The "connection lost contact" messages indicate that there's a problem in your network. Perhaps you have a router or a bridge which is failing.

Comment: hi @BobJarvis the issue is very sporadic. It is not like that it is happening each and every call

Comment: you might want to ask your DBA if s/he sees anything in the alert log, sometimes there is a server-side error that is ending the connection.  One other idea, once we had an issue where a firewall was terminating the oracle network connection, we put "sqlnet.expire_time=10" in the sqlnet.ora on the server and it sends a ping every 10 minutes, that was enough to keep the firewall from closing the connection

Comment: just reconnect on exception, same way you would do on forced server-side timeout.

Comment: But while opening a connection it is not throwing any exception. Every during ExecuteNonQuery() it's throwing the exception .